# Using Bank Statements or Payslips for Canadian Tourist visa Application?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

I own and run a startup.
I want to come to Canada on a tourist visa. My startup does cross-border payments, so I want to come in person to meet with some VC's and discuss talks as regards funding for my startup. I want to submit documentation, but somewhere I see bank statements or payslips.

Since I have my own startup, is there a need to present bank statements or do I present payslips instead? Just asking for clarity's sake.

**Edit**

Please see what I mean

[image: ginger.png]

Comment: Why would your being the owner of a startup have anything to do with whether you need to show your bank statements as part of a visa application?

Comment: @phoog that is why i said for Clarity sakes, because its what i saw on the Website that got me very confused. hence the question

Comment: What website?  What did you see there?

Comment: @phoog https://cic.gc.ca

Comment: @phoog, check edits

Comment: You presumably derive your income from your start-up. You need to present statements for both your start-up *and* your personal bank accounts. Ideally IMHO you should also show your business’ financial accounts that demonstrate *profitability* sufficient to support your personal drawings, not just turnover. This https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab relates to a UK visitor visa but is applicable in general when applying elsewhere

Comment: @Traveller, well explained. This is the answer i needed. Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

You presumably derive your income from your start-up. You need to present statements for both your start-up and your personal bank accounts. Ideally IMHO you should also show your most recent tax return, and your business’ financial accounts that demonstrate profitability sufficient to support your personal drawings, not just turnover.

This [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) relates to a UK visitor visa but is applicable in general when applying elsewhere

Comment: Makes sense! If i have access to the accounts by which investment money is being paid into, do I present that>?

Comment: @Bluelime Depends what you mean by ‘have access to’. Typically you should provide evidence of the *source* of deposits into accounts in your / your business’ name, especially when such deposits are out of the norm.